# Encode photos into (some) video format in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, gif

In my app I need to convert photos (taken by the user) into some playable (on both Android device and pc web browser) vide format.

My first and obvious choice was GIF, I've managed to get it working using this https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder but the result was of very poor quality. What I didn't now was gif is a terrible standard - only 256 colors per frame, virtually no compression, so for my purposes it's useless.

I know it is possible to use ffmpeg for this, but I have no experience with NDK (and I've used C only at the university).

Are there any other options worth exploring?

EDIT: it needs to work on ICS (minSdkVersion=15)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) (for android over 4.3)  to convert your images to mp4.

Comment: I've came across this in some SO question, but it needs to work on API 15 (I've edited my question to include that)

Comment: Did you try MediaCodec, it should work for the earlier versions.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of how to do it? Of how to provide each frame and its duration, and generate the MP4 from them all?